# What is wrong with this line of MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, matrix-indexing

When I try to run this line of code in MATLAB:

```
image_arr(i,:,:) = medfilt2(image_arr(i,:,:), [9 9])
```

it errors:

```
Error using medfilt2
Expected input number 1, A, to be two-dimensional.
```

`image_arr` is an `n * x_max * y_max` array containing `n`, `x_max` by `y_max` images in grayscale.  Is this stored improperly?  I have seen mention of `x_max` by `y_max` by `n` arrays in the documentation...

In this case, `image_arr` is a `29`x`1536`x`2048` array, whose members are all of the `single` type.

Comment: The error is indicating that `image_arr(i, :, :)` is not `2D` can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: Added some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
>> img = rand(5, 100, 200);
>> size(img(1,:,:))
ans =
     1   100   200
```

You wanna get rid of that leading singleton dimension:

```
squeeze(img(1,:,:))
```

or:

```
permute(img(1,:,:), [2 3 1])
```